# RESTful url in android with (')

Tags: url, url-encoding

I am developing an android application and I am using a RESTful service to connect to SQL azure database. I need to use this RESTful url:

```
http://example.com/wcfDataService1.svc/wn_synset?$filter=word%20eq%20'child's_game'&$select=synset_id,w_num,word,ss_type,wn_gloss/gloss&$expand=wn_gloss
```

As you can see am looking for this word (`child's_game`) in the table `wn_synset`.
The problem is the single quote `(')` in `child's_game`. As you can see it puts the word inside quotes `'...'` so when it finds the quote in `child's_game` it thinks it is the end of the word and the rest is error.

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can url-encode the ' symbols with `%27`. See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp and try it in the "Try it yourself" section.

**Edit:** (moved correct guess from comments to the answer itself)

Or is it just, that the SQL-Server on the server side gets it wrong? Like it builds a select * from wn_synset where word = 'child's game' and there's the error? Then you'll have to look up how you escape single quotes for your database -- probably it's by using two single quotes (''), so perhaps try to send child''s game instead of child's game.

Comment: It is not working for me. My problem is how to till him that ' in child's_game it is not the end of the word (it is not the closing brackets)

Comment: Who is this 'him' you're talking about? Perhaps post some of your code. Or is it just, that the SQL-Server on the server side gets it wrong? Like it builds a `select * from wn_synset where word = 'child's game'` and there's the error? Then you'll have to look up how you escape single quotes for your database -- probably it's by using two single quotes (`''`), so perhaps try to send `child''s game` instead of `child's game`.

Comment: yahoooooo it worked thaaankyou very much i was stuck with this problem for month thank you thank you. Yes i mean by him the server side (soory my english is not the good, you described my problem in nice way (how you escape single quotes for your database)).

Comment: @user1856811 You achieve this by escaping the original string, either by methods from `URLEncoder` or `Uri` as I suggested in my answer, or, if it's a fixed string, by replacing the ' character with its escape sequence, as Ridcully mentioned.

Comment: This sloution work 'child''s game' but this 'child%27's game' dose not work it gives me error. Thank you all for helping me.

Comment: @user1856811 I edited my answer to add the correct solution from the comment. You should accept my answer then as the correct one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem, or in other words, your URL is not a URL. If it were a URL, ther wouldn't be a '. Of course, you can have this ' in your URL, so to speak. But it needs to be escaped in accordance with the rules for URLs. You may want to look at [URLEncoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html) and [Uri](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html).